# Is there a way to test every function call permutation including default params?

Tags: python, pytest

Assuming I have a function like this: `def foo(a, b)`, I can test its call with:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1,2,3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", [1,2,3])
def test_foo(a, b):
    foo(a, b)
```

However, having a default param complicates it a bit. If I change the function into `def foo(a, *,  b=0)`, testing it gets complicated:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1,2,3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", [1,2,3])
def test_foo(a, b):
    foo(a, b=b)
```

but I also want to verify the default param for `b` works, i.e. test the call `foo(a)`. Is it possible to tweak this test in a nice way so it would also test it?

My only thought is something like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1,2,3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", [1,2,3,None])
def test_foo(a, b):
    if b:
        foo(a, b=b)
    else:
        foo(a)
```

or split this into multiple tests, but it looks silly and non-elegant. Any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1,2,3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("kwargs", [{"b": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"b": 3}, {}])
def test_foo(a, kwargs):
   foo(a, **kwargs)
```

or maybe keeping more with your original idea but a slightly more clean invocation:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1,2,3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", [1, 2, 3, None])
def test_foo(a, b):
   kwargs = {"b": b} if b is not None else {}
   foo(a, **kwargs)
```